# set maximum value to a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column (int type) called age. This column should hold maximun value 50. If it exceeds then it shouldn't update that row.

Means this column shold take values from 0 to 50.

If I try to update that to 51 then that shouldn't allow.

Could any one help....!

Comment: Why do you use wrong data type then? ENUM is what you need, not INT.

Comment: I think a trigger is the right way for you...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.age<0 OR NEW.age>50 THEN
    CALL `Error: Wrong values for age`; -- this trick will throw an error
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: For @Gnanendra: @nick rulez set age to null if user is inserting something wrong; my example raise an error. Use what you think is the best for your situation!!

Comment: @Gnanendra: Take a look even at this interesting article http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints

Comment: @Gnanendra: what about accepting an answer among the ones given to you? ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
create table test (
age tinyint not null ) engine = myisam;

delimiter //
drop trigger if exists max_num//
create trigger max_num before insert on test
for each row 
begin
if new.age < 0 or new.age > 50 then
set new.age = null;
end if;
end//
delimiter ;

insert into test (age) values (100);
```

Make the same thing for update.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
Name VARCHAR(80), 
Age  INT CHECK (Age BETWEEN 5 and 50));
```

Comment: Even worse, MySQL lets you create a table using this definition but the constraint is ignored by the parser and not added in the table!

Comment: Does anybody know if there are plans of the `CHECK` constraint to be added in future versions of any MySQL db engine?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL introduced check constraints in MySQL 8.0.16 and now the check constraints are enforced as you would reasonably expect.
See [MySQL 8.0.16 introduced check constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/).
So, you can achieve your goal by altering your `age` column using the statement below.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `YOUR_TABLE_NAME` MODIFY `age` TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 CHECK(`age` <= 50);
```